# Bootstrap Timepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am trying to find a time picker widget, compatible with bootstrap styling.  I really like the style of the [jdewit](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker) widget, but it has a tremendous number of bugs.  I am trying to finish this project quickly, so I don't want to get bogged down in fixing library bugs.

Can anyone else recommend a slick timepicker that is production ready?

Comment: bootstrap is important for consistent styling and RAD

Comment: the jdewit version works pretty well as of today at least. Maybe some minor issues, but overall a really good and useful plugin

Answer (score 8):

I'm the author of the jdewit/timepicker.

I finally took some time to get through all the reported issues. Hope it meets your needs.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>You could try our one https://github.com/Bloafer/bootstrap-timepicker</strike>

We are now using this one https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker as it is being actively developed

Comment: jdewit/timepicker is much better.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use https://github.com/Bloafer/bootstrap-timepicker, it didn't find it very helpful as it needed to have the time format as HH:MM, whereas mine were being supplied as HH:MM:SS.  Also the styling is not the best.

This is also a problem for me, I have tried 4 timepickers and all of them have some kind of issue under bootstrap, I would like to see an answer to this as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js

I'm the author of this thing.

You'd use with something like this:

```
var timepicker = new TimePicker(['field1', 'field2'], {
  theme: 'dark', // or 'blue-grey'
  lang: 'pt' // 'en', 'pt' for now
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt){
  console.info(evt);

  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;
});
```